# Programmaticlaly moving rows with animation in UITableView 

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, animation, core-animation

I want to move a row to the bottom of my `UITableView` with cool animation effect just like in [this Grocery Shopping List app](http://www.grocerygadgets.com/how-grocery-gadgets-work.aspx).

Just like we can move rows with reordering control like:

[image: reordering uitableview rows programmatically]

How can I create such animation?

Answer (score 25):

In IOS 5 this can be done with the following `UITableView` selector:

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

For example:

```
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[items count] - 1 inSection:1]];
```

Comment: great ! link to the selector doc : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW55

Comment: The obvious followup question is how to figure out these indexPaths after sorting an array...? Perhaps I should make a sorted copy of the array and figure out the before and after indexes of each element?

Answer (score 8):

**Important: This answer assumes iPhone OS 3.x. [See the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8911788/224671) for iOS 5.x**

I don't know what is the "cool animation effect just like in Grocery Shopping List app". Not everyone has that app.

---

Rows cannot be moved programmatically.

However, you can simultaneously insert and delete a row to simulate a move.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:rowToMove]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathToMoveTo]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
// update your dataSource as well.
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Kenny,

The effect I was talking about is a falling row  animation, just like dragging it with a finger when a table is in rearrange mode.
I'm wondering how it was done. I think about drawing the cell content into semi transparent uiimage and then move the image with animation into desired location, but i'm not sure that's the best solution

Comment: You find a solution? I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112588/how-make-the-same-animation-like-uitableview-reorder-of-cells & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315990/how-copy-cells-between-tables-as-the-pulse-app

Comment: maybe you just need to RowAnimation effect to :UITableViewRowAnimationBottom

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of similar to what I have done to allow drag and drop from one scrollview to another.

You will want to create a duplicate/dummy cell (for visual effect), then remove the original cell, then animate the duplicate, then insert into the bottom and then finally remove the duplicate/dummy cell.