# Reordering UITableView rows programmatically with animation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I very much know how to reorder `UITableView` rows using "reorder Control" by the user.

By implementing `UITableView` delegates and datasource methods as it is [provided in apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1).

But I want the same functionality programmatically.

I need this in the scenario when a row/cell is updated I want reordering according to that update time or some other criteria.

I've seen this functionality in [this grocery list app](http://www.grocerygadgets.com/how-grocery-gadgets-work.aspx).

I want reordering with animation.

Comment: duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313252/programaticlaly-moving-rows-with-animation-in-uitableview

Answer (score 2):

Check out the UITableView reference.

You may want to use these methods:

```
– beginUpdates
– endUpdates
– insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
– insertSections:withRowAnimation:
– deleteSections:withRowAnimation:
```