# xCode... Table Views in Distance Order

Tags: xcode

In my app I am trying to make different venues, go into distance order within a table view, so that the customer can see what place is nearest to him, with this constantly changing...

any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reordering UITableView rows programmatically with animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936917/reordering-uitableview-rows-programmatically-with-animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold the venues as NSDictionaries (venue, distance) in an array and sort the array by distance in ascending order ..... Make the array the datasource of the Table View.