# How make the same animation like UITableView reorder of cells?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios4, drag-and-drop

I have a drag&drop operation [between 2 UITableViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061693/how-move-reorder-cells-from-tableview1-to-tableview2). The cell could be reordered in the source TableView, or move to another TableView.

Because I need to move the cell between the two, I can't use the default reorder support. However, I want to make a similar animation like when the cell is moving around and the cell below them slide out.

Any hint in how do this animation?

UPDATE:

You can see what exactly I'm looking for in the [pulse app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pulse-news-reader/id371088673?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to remove it from the source and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert it into the destination.

Comment: This is not the thing I'm looking for. Check the pulse app. Is the reorder animation while the cell is moving on top the tableView, and the cells below it push away...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something similar to what makes "Pulse" you have to use "UIScrollView" for each row that you have and within the Views you need, if you do it UITableView is more complicated and would not be so easy to move between them